# how to make executable from assembly language?(in emacs)

Tags: linux, gcc, emacs, assembly, ubuntu

Could somebody tell me how to make executable from assembly language?
my environment is Ubuntu + Emacs + GCC
for learning purpose, I wrote some C code(hello.c) and convert it to assembly (hello.s)

and I want to make an executable file from an assembly written file.

I tried

```
M-x compile

gcc hello.c -S
```

to make assembly from C code

and

```
M-x compile

as hello.s
```

to make executable file

but there's only a.out file and it isn't able to execute

so I tried

```
as hello.s -o aaa
```

but file "aaa" is not executable

Comment: Try to change the permissions of aaa "chmod +x aaa"

Comment: I don't think it's matter of permission.
it's object code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The output of `as` is an object file. To make it executable you need to link it with `ld` but you will also need to link in any objects it depends on, which if the source was generated from gcc, will at least include libc, as well as probably some other object files.

Comment: thank you so much!
gcc hello.s -o aaa.
that's just what I want it!!